# Склонение полного наименования организации

Tags: склонение

Как правильно склонять:
1) Правила внутреннего распорядка Публичного акционерного общества "N" или
2) Правила внутреннего распорядка Публичное акционерное общество "N"?
Прошу обосновать ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **Правила внутреннего распорядка Публичного акционерного общества "111" .**

Это составное имя собственное,  оно склоняется. Обычно не склоняются названия, заключенные в кавычки (при наличии родового наименования).

Пример: Правила Открытого акционерного общества (ОАО) «Подольский машиностроительный завод».

Comment: По-моему, название тут "111". Почему Открытое  и Публичное с заглавной?

Comment: В официальных названиях предприятий  используются ДВА НАИМЕНОВАНИЯ (по виду собственности  и по роду деятельности). Пример: 1) Открытое акционерное общество (ОАО) «Московский завод «Кристалл» – имя собственное (официальное название) 2)   сокращенная запись:  Московский завод «Кристалл» – имя собственное; 3) упрощенная запись:  завод «Кристалл» – приложение перед именем собственным..